# Computer will not boot / hardware malfunctions after replacing graphics card

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-vista, graphics-card, bios

**The current problem:** my computer will not boot. Each time there are different issues but the common factor is that it never gets in to Windows 7. The most common problem is that, about 30 seconds after powering on, the keyboard becomes unresponsive and then booting stops. In the first 30 seconds, the Num Lock key is working but after then, if I press Num Lock, the Num Lock light goes on for a split second only.

The most recent problem is that I see:

> BOOTMGR image is corrupt. The system cannot boot.

Sometimes it just goes into a loop where the graphics card splash screen is shown every 20 seconds or so - like the boot sequence keeps starting anew.

I can go into the BIOS, but I have to make changes quickly before the keyboard locks. There I can see that sometimes the DVD drive is not available.

For the history of how I got here, see **The full story** below. Current situation is that Windows 7 installation is begun but not completed. Occasionally it tries booting into safe mode and then says that it cannot complete the installation in safe mode.

**How can I get the system up and running again?**

**What I have tried:** My guess is that there is a general issue with power. I have followed the instructions on various sites (eg [pcsupport](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbysymptom/ht/nopowertopc.htm) and [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-PC-Which-Won't-Boot)) which includes:

- different power cables
- different wall outlet
- resetting BIOS settings
- new CMOS battery
- remounting most of hardware (graphics card, memory, etc)
- removed non-essential boards (sound & network)

**The full story:** I had a Windows Vista computer that took at least 10 minutes to boot and often did not boot at all. So I wanted to start afresh with a Windows 7 installation (wiping everything).

I booted Windows Vista in safe mode and put all the files I wanted to keep on an external hard drive. Then I installed Windows 7 without any problems. I noticed though that some of my previous files were still present (it turned out that I had installed Windows 7 on a fresh partition). I also noticed after booting again that the computer was no longer able to start Windows 7 in anything other than safe mode (as with Vista).

After looking online I concluded there was possibly a problem with my graphics card ([SAPPHIRE HD 4850 1GB GDDR3 PCI-E HDMI](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?psn=0001&pid=214&lid=1)). I physically removed it (to read all the type information so that I could download the correct drivers) and replaced it. That is when the **current problem** occurred.

*I will add more details (eg hardware) as requested.*

Comment: Reinstall W7, this time put it on the correct partition. Or you could delete all partitions during windows 7 setup, then install it to the new single partition.

Comment: @Moab, thanks, I had already done that. I have in the meantime found the (unbelievably obvious) solution which I will post here. Now I have a new problem (next question...).

Comment: Vote to close as problem can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: @DavidPostill: where do you get that from? Problem **can** be reproduced if I pull the DVD power cable out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was embarrassingly simple. Somehow the power cable to the DVD had become loose. Fixing that (and then resetting the BIOS by removing and replacing the CMOS battery) enabled me to boot and complete the Windows 7 installation.

Comment: "I also noticed after booting again that the computer was no longer able to start Windows 7 in anything other than safe mode (as with Vista)."  what does this have to do with a dvd drive, no way it can cause this boot issue. Your original question is obviously lacking important detail.

Comment: @Moab: hmmmm, I also had to remove and replace the CMOS battery, will add that. That is part of the follow up question.